# How can I avoid repeat "I" in sentence?

Tags: word-usage, pronouns, repetition, rhythm

I'd like describe my father :

> First at all, when **I** decide to do some work, **I** don't worry because **I** know my father is behind me

I use 3 times of "I" how can I change sentence for decrease "I"?

Comment: It's no problem, though I can reduce it. **First of all, while doing some work, I don't worry remembering the fact that my father is behind me, always.**

Comment: @Man_From_India - (IMHO) your example sounds a bit unnatural. I would change "remembering" to "because of".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal and it sounds fine to repeat **I** three times in a sentence like that. The word **I** is tiny, so it doesn't make your sentence seem long. Repeating **I** makes your sentence easier to follow than altered versions of the sentence where **I** is not repeated.

The purpose of pronouns is to avoid repeating longer words. The pronouns themselves are very short: **I**, **me**, **you** **he**, **him**, **she**, **her**, **it**, **they**, **them**. So, repeating them is not a problem. The pronouns **I** and **me** just stand for the speaker, but it's still okay to repeat them.

Here is a version of your sentence with no occurrences of **I**:

> First of all, when Mohammad decides to do some work, Mohammad doesn't worry because Mohammad knows his father is behind him.

That sounds a little crazy, though. Only crazy people and Julius Caesar talk about themselves in the third person.

Here are some versions with one or two **I**'s:

> First of all, when deciding to do some work, I don't worry because my father is behind me.
>
> First of all, when deciding to do some work, I don't worry because the fact that my father is behind me is known to me.
>
> First of all, when I decide to do some work, I don't worry because my father is behind me.
>
> First of all, when I decide to do some work, there is no worry for me because it is known to me that my father is behind me.

The first three of these don't say exactly what you wanted to say, and none are as clear as your original sentence. The phrase "deciding to do some work" is slightly harder to understand because the word **I** is missing! The clearest way to speak and write in English is just to say the subject and then the verb.

### Stress

Another reason repeating **I** might be less objectionable than you expect is that when subject pronouns (**I**, **you**, **he**, **she**, **it**, **they**) are spoken, they're usually unstressed. I've marked in bold the syllables that a native speaker would probably stress when saying your original sentence:

> **First** of **all**, **when** I de**cide** to **do** some **work**, I **don't** **worr**y be**cause** I **know** my **fa**ther is be**hind** me.

Because **me** is often stressed and **I** is usually unstressed, the repetitions of **me** are actually more noticeable and awkward than the repetitions of **I**.

Answer (score 2):

> First at all, when I decide to do some work, I don't worry because I know my father is behind me

You can try this:

> First of all, there's no worry for me in setting out to do some work, since I know that my father is behind me.
>
> First of all, I have no worry when setting out to do some work, because my father is behind me.

You can use different "*[non-finite clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_clause)*" instead of "*finite clauses*".

Comment: +1 for striking out the "I know" part of the sentence in your second example. It shortens the sentence, making it more direct, while eliminating one of the I's.